# iPad Split View App when I show the detail the button disappears

Tags: split, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I'm making an iPad app and I have a problem when showing the detail view.

Here is my code:

```
NSArray *controllers = self.splitViewController.viewControllers;

DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
[detailViewController setDetailItem:[arrayRevisiones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [controllers objectAtIndex:0];
UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

NSArray *newControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];

self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = newControllers;
[vistaTabla deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

I know the problem is that I'm not adding the button anywhere but I don't know where to add it.